# Make ECB of emacs open by default for .c, .cpp and .cu files

Tags: emacs, emacs-ecb

I recently discovered the Emacs code browsing package (ECB) and it seems to be very useful.

I would like to activate ECB mode by default **only** when I open .c, .cu, cpp and .py files.

Please let me know how I should modify my .emacs file for this.

Thank you,

Gaurish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably best to follow the setting up semantic and file parisng guide for ECB here. 
[ECB File Semantic](http://www.xemacs.org/Documentation/sources/xemacs-packages/packages/xemacs-packages/ecb/ecb_1.html#SEC7)